# how to correctly write drush sql-sycn using drush_invoke_process()

Tags: 7, drush

I need to execute a drush command from a custom module, Im using drush_invoke_process() but I do not know how to write it correctly

How would you write this command for use with drush_invoke_process() ?

```
drush sql-sync @site1 @site2 --tables-list table1,table2,tableN
```

How to write the above command in drush_invoke_process() syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your php code:

```
$values = drush_invoke_process('@none', 'sql-sync', array('@site1', '@site2'), array('tables-list' => 'table1,table2,tableN'));
```

`$values` will be an array containing various interesting information about the Drush call.  In particular, check `$values['error']` to see if the command succeeded or not.

Comment: Hi, I did exactly what you wrote but I got Fatal Error: Call to undefined function drush_invoke_process() Do you know what could happen?

Comment: Did you make the call from a Drush extension?  Are you using a recent version of Drush?  drush_invoke_process has been around since Drush 3, so I am guessing that you are trying to call Drush from some non-Drush code. You'll have to explain your environment.  If you want to call Drush from a Drush command, see the drushify project (http://drupal.org/project/drushify)